# KineticJS - Crop fill image

Tags: image, crop, fill, kineticjs

I'm trying to use a tileset in my game. I want to crop the fill image but can't because

1. I can't fill a shape with a Kinetic.Image() object.
2. I can't crop a Image() object.

   ```
   var rect = new Kinetic.Rect({  
       x: 0,  
       y: 0,  
       width: 64,  
       height: 64,  
       fill:{  
           image: imageObj,  
           crop:{  
               x: 128,  
               y: 128,  
               width: 64,  
               height: 64  
           },   
       },  
           strokeWidth: 1  
   });
   ```

This doesn't work, and I also can't replace image: imageObj with a Kinetic.Image() object that is precropped. Any ideas?

**EDIT:** Looks like it might be possible by drawing the Kinetic.Image to the scene, using toDataUrl to load the cropped Kinetic.Image into a image object useable by fill, then continue with the map script. This introduces a ton of performance issues/loading times so I'm going to go ahead and assume what I want to do just isn't feasible. If anyone has any ideas on how to do this properly please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

You can get fill to accept an image, as shown in this example with the Vader/Yoda:

http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/kineticjs/html5-canvas-set-fill-with-kineticjs/

What i'd suggest is loading your images into an array (as he does in the example) then calling the images out as you create the tile.

I changed the code for the first Pentagon to a Rectangle on that example like so:

```
var colorPentagon = new Kinetic.Rect({
      x: 40,
      y: 50,
      width: 100,
      height: 100,
      fill: {
        image: images.darthVader,
        offset: [-220, -70]
      },
      stroke: "black",
      strokeWidth: 4,
      draggable: true
    });
```

And it worked, so no reason that can't give you what you want.

Comment: I believe what the OP was asking for is the ability to use a Kinetic.Rect() but use a CSS sprite image for the fill (what I call a sprite - an image containing multiple smaller images which would be used as background fills for divs in a normal DOM situation, to limit the number of http requests). OP, is there a reason why you can't use Kinetic.Image() with a crop from the sprite instead of Kinetic.Rect() objects?

Comment: Lazerblade - Duh! When I posted this question I had been coding all day. Thanks for the easy fix!